# Combining numbers and strings to generate random output

Tags: excel, vba, random

I have the following code that produces a random number from 1 to 36.  I would actually like to produce a random string from the names btn1 to btn36.  Is there a way to do this?

```
Dim Low As Double
Dim High As Double
Low = 1
High = 36
R = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd() + Low)
Sheets("ITEMS DATA").Range("K21").Value = R
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. A simple string concatenation will work. Just append your random number to a `"btn"` string prefix like this:

```
Sheets("ITEMS DATA").Range("K21").Value = "btn" & R
```